# Installing OpenRave on Ubuntu: Instructions don't work

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get

Official install instructions from here: http://openrave.org/docs/latest_stable/install/

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openrave/release
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openrave
```

but all I get is

```
Unable to locate package openrave
```

I tried looking at the repo here: https://launchpad.net/~openrave/+archive/ubuntu/release

and tried installing  `openrave0.8-sp`, but just getting

```
Couldn't find any package by regex 'openrave0.8-sp'
```

I'm using Ubuntu Trusty. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When filtering for release, the only package available for [Trusty](https://launchpad.net/~openrave/+archive/ubuntu/release?field.series_filter=trusty)) is:

collada-dom2.4-dp

This means that the package you are looking for is not available for your release.

Comment: Ah, okay - so am I out of luck? Do I have to compile from source?

Comment: from what i have read, i guess so ...